# SyntaxError: missing ] after element list [object Object]

Tags: javascript

I got this error in firebug :

```
     SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

    [object Object]
```

for the following javascript piece of code  :

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    setTimeout( function(){
        closeBtn( i,'.lt400' );
        // the error exactly happened in next line:
        setTimeout($('#uploaded-holder').hide(), i * 300 );
    }, i * 300 ); 
}
```

I don't know how a ] can be missing there.. by the way, in chrome i got this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: better `setTimeout( function () {
$('#uploaded-holder').hide()
}, i * 300 );`

Comment: yeah , i did it and it's ok , thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear, it helped :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) expects a function or a string of code as the first parameter. You are passing the result of the evaluation of this expression:

```
$('#uploaded-holder').hide()
```

This expression returns neither a string, nor a function. It returns a jQuery collection.

You want:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#uploaded-holder').hide();
}, i * 300 );
```

You have an odd set of code there, though, given the combination of setTimeouts and the loop. I would expect some wild oddities to come from it once this error is resolved. For example, `i` is not going to be what you expect in the execution of many of those internal functions...

Comment: Or he could simply do `setTimeout($('#uploaded-holder').hide,i*300);`

Comment: @AlexW I have not tested it, but I believe that would lead to scoping issues with `this` inside of the jQuery collection instance

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use this:-

```
setTimeout( function () 
{ $('#uploaded-holder').hide() }, i * 300 );
```

instead of

```
setTimeout($('#uploaded-holder').hide(), i * 300 );
```

as [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) expects a string or a function as first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this , this also works

setTimeout(" $('#uploaded-holder').hide() ", i * 300 );

Add the first parameter within double quotes.